# How to get an onclick event in a FlowListView?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am using a FlowListView and looks great and awesome! But I am having some problems to get it working with onclick events.

This is my Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:flv="clr-namespace:DLToolkit.Forms.Controls;assembly=DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView"
         x:Class="EscapeHaarlem.Views.ItemsPage"
          Title="{Binding Title}"
         x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="46*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="38*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
        <flv:FlowListView Grid.Row="0" FlowColumnCount="2"   
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"   
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            FlowItemTapped="FlowListView_FlowItemTapped"
            FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}"   
            FlowItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

            <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="ForestGreen" Margin="5">
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Fill"   
                VerticalOptions="Fill"   
                TextColor="White"  
                XAlign="Center"  
                YAlign="Center"   
                Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="Emergeny" BackgroundColor="DarkRed"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Where I thought that `FlowItemTapped="FlowListView_FlowItemTapped"` was used for the onclick event.

But when I use the following function for the clickevent it wont trigger:

```
async void FlowListView_FlowItemTapped(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");

        if (answer == true)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        // Manually deselect item.
        //ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

How can I make those items clickable?

This is the layout for the xaml you're seeing

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: try removing `FlowItemTappedCommand`

Comment: Mhmm wil try but why should that give interference?

Comment: because you have both an event handler AND a command assigned to the same action

Comment: Which version are you use of FlowList because i have use but i have not SelectedItemChangedEventArgs. i have ItemTappedEventArgs.

Comment: The newest .11 if I am not mistaken. Ik also tried ItemTappedEventArgs but I can't get it to work either.

Comment: @Jason Just tried your suggestion but it won't work

Comment: Does the command been called ? Your code works fine on my side . So you would better share your sample so that I can test it .

Comment: Hi, I fixed it with FlowItemTapped="FlowListView_FlowItemTapped". But there is one thing I have some problem with sometimes it won't recognize the tapped item and no pop up will show up. I think this has to do with manually deselect for example with ListView it is as follow: ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null; But I have no idea what could be the problem could you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could create a new thread with more details so that people can help you better .